# How do I blacklist the gallium ATI driver?

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati

Is there a way to stop the gallium driver loading?

Comment: The reason for blacklisting Gallium, which the answer below is not a solution, was to use unity. Researching Gallium led me to Xorg edgers ppa which has installed OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 7.11-devel which appears to allow unity to work with Gallium.

Answer (score 3):

**1) Backup the blacklist file:**

```
sudo cp /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.bak
```

**2) Edit it:**

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

**2) Add this:**

```
blacklist gallium-nouveau 
blacklist gallium-i915  
blacklist gallium-i965  
blacklist gallium-radeon  
blacklist gallium-r600  
blacklist gallium-svga  
blacklist gallium
```

**3) Save and reboot.**

**4) Make sure it works:**

```
lsmod | grep gallium
```

*References:*
 [Prevent a Linux kernel module from auto loading](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/avoid-linux-kernel-module-driver-autoloading.html)
 [Gallium How To](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/GalliumHowto)

Comment: This does appear to stop the module however glxinfo says   OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on ATI RV350

Comment: Changed all the gallium to Gallium and then had two lists but glxinfo still says the same.

Comment: Please note from above this is an ATI RV350 graphics card in a laptop

Comment: I have tried all of your suggestions and can't get any to work

Comment: May be glxinfo is given you the wrong information? Can you try `sudo aptitude purge glxinfo && sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude install glxinfo`?

Comment: I think the problem is the blacklist system isn't working I've just tried to blacklist floppy And it won't take.

Comment: That's weird :-/

Comment: I will search for more.